# Is Backface culling possible on another object?

Tags: rendering, materials, 3d-view, shaders

I've tried backface culling on something like toon shading, and it works with flying colors, however, I wanted to try and make an object contain another using backface culling, but despite the fact that I have seen the node trick to get it to work, and pressed the mark in viewport shading, I still have no use at getting it to work

For example Images, I have this sphere
[image]

And here is the cube on top of this image, with backface culling as the material. As you can see, despite having the sphere underneath, it's not visible. i have tried adding a geometry node with mix shader, but it still did not get the desired results.
[image]

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean when you say backface culling? Backface culling simply means that the backs of faces aren't rendered, only the fronts of faces. So are you trying to have your cube with normals facing in, with backface culling, and that way you would only see the inside faces on the far side of the cube?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Back-face culling means render engine will **ignore** faces which normal is not facing toward camera. Since a newly created cube's normal is *normal* facing outside, you need to filp the normal <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>N</kbd> in mesh edit mode:

[image]

If you want the mesh to be a **mask** and cut of some part of other object, it's not possible with backface culling since the mesh is ignore instead of recalculate.